# How to sort a c++ map in FIFO order?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to sort a C++ map in FIFO order (First In First Out)

In FIFO, we assume that an element will be inserted at the begining, where the remove operation will be donne at the end.

So if we assume the current code is the comparator used to sort the map

`struct classcomp {
  bool operator() (const char& lhs, const char& rhs) const
  {return false;}
};`

If we assume that the first element is the existing one in the map, when the second is the element to insert, is there any chance that my map will be sorted in FIFO order ?

Thanks,

Comment: It can't be done. Your comparator does not satisfy the requirements of `std::map`. Perhaps you need an `std::queue`?

Comment: Or a `std::deque` if random access is also required. Either way, a `std::map` is the wrong container of what it sounds like you're trying.

Comment: That comparator will result in undefined behavior since it doesn't provide a "strict weak ordering". For example, with that comparator, an element will simultaneously be less than, greater than and equivalent to any other element.

Comment: And if you want FIFO ordering, why use a `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem every once in a while and here is my solution: https://github.com/nlohmann/fifo_map. It's a header-only C++11 solution and can be used as drop-in replacement for a `std::map`.

## Example

```
#include "src/fifo_map.hpp"

// for convenience
using nlohmann::fifo_map;

int main() {
    // create fifo_map with template arguments
    fifo_map<int, std::string> m;

    // add elements
    m[2] = "two";
    m[3] = "three";
    m[1] = "one";

    // output the map; will print
    // 2: two
    // 3: three
    // 1: one
    for (auto x : m) {
        std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << "\n";
    }

    // delete an element
    m.erase(2);

    // re-add element
    m[2] = "zwei";

    // output the map; will print
    // 3: three
    // 1: one
    // 2: zwei
    for (auto x : m) {
        std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note how the `fifo_map`'s elements are always printed in the order of the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

A map and any standard associative container is already sorted and it cannot be sorted differently.

If you would like to maintain several element orders in one container, e.g. sorted by some key (map) and in order of insertion (list), you can do that with [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), it is very well documented.